# I want to Unable and disable multi level menu item based on condition in struts2

Tags: menu, struts2, struts-1, struts-config, struts1

What i Have Basically Struts2 Multilevel menu

```
Parent item
   |-sub item
   |-sub item
parent item
   |-sub item
   |-sub item
```

likewise, So Here i want to unable and disable sub item(menu) based on condition(flag). for this repository is set already.

Comment: Please show us a code-snippet

Comment: Set your variable in your respective action and wrap your submenu in an <s:if> clause.